# Accessing User's Environment Variables in Python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am developing an interface for accessing user's environment variables using python. I have a list of system users, when selected a specific user, I want to print its environment. What I have tried so far seem to only print the variables of the current user. How can I write a script that will loop through all existing system users and print their environment?

```
def get_user_env(self, name):
    return "USERNAME: " + os.environ.get("USER") + "\n\nHOME: " +os.environ["HOME"] + "\n\nPATH: " + os.environ["PATH"]

def display_environment(self):
    name = str(self.listUsers.currentItem().text())
    self.listGroups.clear()
    groups = self.get_group_list(name)
    env = self.get_user_env(name)
    users = self.listUsers.selectedItems()
    for group in groups:
        self.listGroups.addItem(QtGui.QApplication.translate("test_gui", group, None))
        self.textUser.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("test_gui", env , None))
```

Comment: `os.environ` won't help you there. If you're on windows you'll have to load the user registry, and on linux, you'll have to parse users bashrc or other to see which variables are defined. Good luck with that!!

Comment: Users don't have environment variables. Processes have environment variables, and different processes with the same user can have different environment variables. What your program does is to print the environment of the current process. Can you describe more precisely what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: do you mean the user PATH variable

Comment: @JamesD yes I mean PATH variable